# Intellisense not recognizing variables returned by sklearn as array type

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pylance

(my environment is vs code using pylance)

For example, arrays returned from `train_test_split()` or `LinearRegression.predict()` are not recognized as an array and do not offer any autocomplete suggestions. In google colab and spyder after typing `my_returned_array.`, I get a long list of available array functions, but in VS code with pylance I get nothing.

Is there some additional configuration I need to do or is there some other extension I need to use?

Comment: Have you installed the python extension? Could you run your code correctly? As it works well on my computer with pylance language server.

Answer (score 1):

Google Colab and Spyder maintain the state of all variables as parts of the program are run. VS Code does a similar thing with the Jupyter Notebooks extension while running in debug mode, allowing me to explore the states of variables, but pylance doesn't seem to pick up state information from the Jupyter notebook. While this would be a wonderful feature, it is not a necessary behavior.